# Unable to distinguish four cosines from a FFT

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, dft

I have four cosines with frequencies 400e-3, 500e-3, 600e-3 and 700e-3 and I am trying to do the FFT of them but under the time I need, I cannot distinguish the four. Is there a way to distinguish the peaks without changing the tmax time of 1.76 and the frequencies?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq
from scipy.fft import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.linspace(0,1.76,2400) 
f = [400e-3, 500e-3, 600e-3, 700e-3] # these are the frequencies
yy = 0

for i in f:
    y = 0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*i*t)
    yy = yy + y

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(t, yy)


f = fftfreq(len(t), np.diff(t)[0])
yf = fft(yy)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(f[:t.size//2], np.abs(yf[:t.size//2]))
plt.show()
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Comment: The FFT doesn’t have enough resolution to distinguish these. You need to sample for a lot longer to distinguish them using the FFT. longer sampling = more resolution. You might be able to estimate the frequencies in some other way though, I don’t know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to increase tmax of

```
t = np.linspace(0,1.76,2400)
```

i.e. 1.76. FFT makes bins the size of 1/tmax and the small tmax is, the bigger the bins are leading to less resolution.